# SOAP webservice return a custom Apex class

Tags: apex, soap

I have an Apex SOAP endpoint defined like this:

```
global class CancelTransferOrderSoapService {

   webservice static OrderContactDetails cancelTransferOrder(
    String orderId
    , List<String> contactIdList
    , String reason
    , String comment
    , String newOrderStatus
    , Boolean bWaiveFee
    , Boolean bUpdate) {

      ...
      return orderContactDetails;
   }
}
```

Where the value returned is the following custom Apex class:

```
   global class rsOrderContactDetails {
       @AuraEnabled @InvocableVariable global String orderId;
       @AuraEnabled @InvocableVariable global String contactId;
   }
```

I'm not seeing the data in the custom class in the response.  Is this not possible with an Apex SOAP method?  Or do I need to define the custom class and/or its properties differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must mark variables to be returned as `webservice`.

```
global class rsOrderContactDetails {
  @AuraEnabled @InvocableVariable webservice String orderId;
  @AuraEnabled @InvocableVariable webservice String contactId;
}
```

Which also makes the properties take on the `global` access level.

Comment: Brilliant!  Thanks!